# How do maintain different production.rb files on different branches of the same project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment

We have a Rails app that's deployed on two servers. One server uses the `master` branch while the other uses the `staging` branch. We use staging internally to test the application, and then we merge with master and deploy.

The `staging` branch has different email settings in `config/production.rb` than the master branch. How can I maintain different `production.rb`/email settings for each branch while still merging everything else?

Adding the file to `.gitignore` would pull it from the repo, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make another environment called `staging`.

Other option is to put the environment file in shared folder on server and link to it while deploying.

Comment: I have to advise against this.  Rails environments should be used for Rails framework configuration, not custom app configuration.  If you are trying to mimic your production env as a "staging" box, that app should be be run under `RAILS_ENV=production`.  

For app specific differences between your live production and "staging" make your own ENV variables or other flags to use for app level configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Dont put these settings into production.rb.  Use an initializer file in config/initializers/email.rb (or something like that) to set these initial settings based on `Rails.env`